# Can`t comprehend the bitwise operations

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

Reading the K&R book I stumbled upon chapter 2.9 which describes bitwise operators in C. Right in the beginning there is this claim:

> The bitwise AND operator & is often used to mask off some set of bits, for example
>   n = n & 0177;
>   sets to zero all but the low-order 7 bits of n.

I am a bit confused with the true meaning of it. How does hexadecimal (if i got it right) 0177 represent low-order 7 bits? I tried to test it in code and below is what I did:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n = 1490;
    n = n & 0177;
    printf("%i\n", n);
}
```

The output of the code is 82. Converting 1490 to binary I got 10111010010 and after setting all bits to zero apart from 7 low order bits i ended up with 1010010 which really equals 82 in decimal. Trying to understand the logic under the hood I applied &(AND) operator manually but it resulted in a completely different number. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please be aware that `0177` is the **octal** (not hexadecimal) form of `01111111`. That leading `0` tells the compiler to interpret it that way. All the l.s. bits are set, so all the matching coresponding bits of the target will be preserved. So the statement "all but (**except**) the lowest bits will be set to `0`" is correct. Each octal digit represent 3 bits.

Comment: @WeatherVane thank you very much for clarification! I had no clue that the octal form was meant there.

Comment: Not surprising that you missed this. Octal was common in 16-bit days but got cumbersome with longer word sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please be aware that `0177` is not hexadecimal but the **octal** form of binary `01111111`. Each octal digit represent 3 bits, and the leading `0` tells the compiler to interpret it that way.

So the operation is

```
decimal 1490    10111010010
octal   0177    00001111111
            AND -----------
decimal 82      00001010010
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler interprets prefix 0 as base 8.

So 177(8) = 127(10) = 1111111(2).

That's your 7 bits right there.